# Cutting the output of a dspmq command

Tags: unix, cut, mq

I am trying to cut the output of the dspmq command

This is the output given:

```
QMNAME(QMGR)                                              STATUS(Running)
QMNAME(QMGR)                                              STATUS(Ended Normally)
QMNAME(QMGR)                                              STATUS(Ended Unexpectedly)
QMNAME(QMGR)                                              STATUS(Running)
```

This is how I would like the output to look:

```
QMGR Running
QMGR Ended Normally
QMGR Ended Unexpectedly 
QMGR Running
```

I have tried various combinations of the cut command with no luck or success. Any help would be much appreciated.

This is the closest I have got:

```
dspmq | cut -d "(" -f 2 | cut -d ")" -f 1
```

Which basically just outputs

```
QMGR
QMGR
QMGR
QMGR
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this `awk`,

```
awk -F'[()]' '{ print $2, $4}'
```

**Test:**

```
$ awk -F'[()]' '{ print $2, $4}' file
QMGR Running
QMGR Ended Normally
QMGR Ended Unexpectedly
QMGR Running
```