# Perl Unable to truncate string

Tags: string, perl, ibm-mq, truncate

I am trying to extract AAA and BBB from the output of the command "dspmq". 
$`dspmq` <- this command gives output as -->

```
QMNAME(AAA)                                           STATUS(Running)
QMNAME(BBB)                                           STATUS(Running)
```

But it doesn't work with the below code.

```
perl -e 'use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);my @qmgrlist = `dspmq`;$size = @qmgrlist;foreach my $i (@qmgrlist){my @temp1 = split /QMNAME\(/, $i;print @temp1;}'
```

```
AAA)                                           STATUS(Running)

BBB)                                           STATUS(Running)
```

I am able to truncate `"QMNAME("` but unable to truncate those to the right of `AAA` and `BBB`. Basically I want to get the string between `"QMNAME("` and the immediate `")"`. Please assist.

Comment: Try **perl -e 'map { print $1 if /QMNAME\((.+?)\)/ } \`dspmq\`'**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a regex approach is better than `split()` here, but you could use `split()` by splitting on parentheses and taking the second item in the returned list.

```
for (@qmgrlist) {
  say +(split /[()]/)[0];
}
```

And a brief note on your use of command-line options to run this code. You can make it simpler if you a) pipe the output of `qspmq` into your code and b) use `-n` to process a record at a time.

```
$ perl -nE 'say +(split /[()]/)[1]' `dspmq`
```

There's also `-M` to load modules (e.g. `-MData::Dumper`), but you don't seem to be using Data::Dumper any more.

Answer (score 3):

`split` isn't going to do what you need. I would just use a regular expression to match the sub-string you need

So change the loop from this

```
foreach my $i (@qmgrlist)
{
    my @temp1 = split /QMNAME\(/, $i;
    print @temp1;
}
```

to this

```
foreach my $i (@qmgrlist)
{
    print "$1\n"
        if /QMNAME\((.+?)\)/;
}
```

Comment: Right approach but the regex is broader than neccessary and it potentially backtracks a lot. `/ ^ QMNAME  \(  ( [^\)]+ )  \) /x` is better.

Comment: Agree that the the regular expression is broader that it could be, but it is fine for the input data set. Why make it more complicated than it needs to be?

Answer (score 3):

Try this perl one-liner:
`dspmq | perl -lne 'print for m{ QMNAME [(] ( [^)]* ) [)] }x'`

---

Here, `dspmq` STDOUT is fed using a pipe `|` into STDIN of the perl code, which has these flags:
`-e` tells Perl interpreter to look for the code inline rather than in a separate script file.
`-n` feeds the input line by line to the inline code (this way you do not need to store the output in an array - this matters for large outputs, not in your case).
`-l` strips the input record separator (newline on *NIX) before feeding it to the code, and appends it automatically after during `print`.

The `print ... for ... m{... (...) ...}` code prints every pattern captured in parentheses.
The captured pattern is `[^)]*`, which is maximum number (0 or more) chars that are **not** (`^`) listed in the character class, that is, that are **not** closing parens.
`[(] ... [)]` are literal parentheses escaped as character classes for readability. I prefer this to escaping like so: `\( ... \)`.
`QMNAME` is used to make the programmer's intentions clear: you want the string that follows QMNAME in parens. I prefer this to using the field index, such as 1, which protects you against minor variation in output of your command used with different options, on different systems, etc.
Finally, the `x` regex modifier in `m{...}x` enables comments and whitespace to be ignored, and is preferred for readability.

**RELATED:**
[Cutting the output of a dspmq command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33097783/cutting-the-output-of-a-dspmq-command)

Comment: Interesting us of `for`.

Answer (score 0):

Desired output can be achieved with following code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

map{ say $1 if /QMNAME\((.+?)\)/ } <DATA>;


__DATA__
QMNAME(AAA)                                           STATUS(Running)
QMNAME(BBB)                                           STATUS(Running)
```

output

```
AAA
BBB
```

and one liner (not tested - I am on Windows computer)

`dspmq | perl -lne 'print $1 if /QMNAME\((.+?)\)/'`